# ActiveCollab Webhooks not working anymore

Tags: activecollab

We use AC 5.13.60. We have a Webhook configured to notify a 3rd party about new discussions.

When we were testing this, it was working properly but in 'real life' it doesn't. The webhook doesn't even get triggered when a new discussion is created or a comment is made.

This is a major problem because every project only has 1 project leader and if he is in vacation, nobody gets notified about new client requests.

Has this webhook stopped working in the latest release?

BTW: It would be great to see events regarding discussions in Zapier as Trigger and not only Tasks! So we could simplify the workflow.

Thanks for any feedback and best regards
Lukas.